# SQL Sorting with a different fields depending on the value of the first one

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Trying to sort data with different fields regarding of the value of the first field.
I thought this would work but i can't find the error

```
Order By 
Case LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int when 10
    then    LGP_Style_Kind_enum,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int,
            LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum,
            LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string
else        LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int,
            LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum,
            LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string end
```

My SQL says syntax error near 'order by'

Besides, how to sort descending LGP_Style_Kind_enum ?

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order and add desc as i needed, i did the following code :

```
Order By 
Case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_Style_Kind_enum end desc,
Case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int end,
LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int,
LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int,
LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum,
LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string
```

Answer (score 0):

A `case` expression returns a *single* value.  A comma delimited list is not a single value.

You can solve this by splitting this into multiple `case` expressions:

```
Order By (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_Style_Kind_enum end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum  end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int = 10 then LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum end),
         (case when LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int <> 10 then LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string end)
```

Note that this splits each column reference into its own `case` expression.  That is intentional.  Otherwise you have to be sure that the types are compatible -- and might get errors if they are not.

Also, this uses `<>` assuming that `LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int` is never `NULL`.  If it can be `NULL`, then the logic needs to take that into account.

Comment: i keep having a syntax error at the first line. Jasper says "no viable alternative at input '('".And my SQL says "#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe près de 'then colorway.LGP_Style_Kind_enum end),"

Comment: this is working when i add when after case, but sql server says "A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique."

Answer (score 0):

```
Order By 
Case LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int when 10
    then    LGP_Style_Kind_enum
else        LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int
end,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC2_int,
            LGP_Colorway_PDC3_int,
            LGP_Style_SAPHrchyLvl2_enum,
            LGP_ShapeMaster_ManualCode_string
```

The result of the case statement should be just one value and then separate the other values with a comma. The way you have it resembles how you may build a sql statement string in code by concatenating all the other fields.

Regardless of which path the logic follows in the case statement, the rest of the sort order would be the same.

Comment: thanks ! i hadn't tought of doing it this way. Where should i place "desc" to order "LGP_Style_Kind_enum" descending ? ( "LGP_Colorway_PDC1_int" should stay ascending)